# ASP.NET Core - CSS background property

Tags: html, css, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I'm working with ASP.NET Core and program a website.

I need a (dynamic) image on the website, which always has the same aspect ratio. So some pictures need to be cropped. I solved this with HTML and CSS as follows:

```
<img class="image-attachment border-bottom border-cgray  " />

<style>
     .image-attachment {
         width: 100%;
         height: 200px;
         background: url('@Context.Request.PathBase\@img.ImagePath') no-repeat center;
         background-size: cover;
     }
</style>
```

But now I have to fill `background:url("")` with a path. If I set the src property on a normal  tag as follows - `@Context.Request.PathBase/@img.ImagePath` - then it works. If I use the same expression in `background:url("")` only an error occurs.

This is the compiled path in the background:url(""): `url(/suchanzeige\\img\Adverts\1\Screenshot 2020-12-30 112140.png)`

and this in the img-src property: `<img src="/suchanzeige/\img\Adverts\1\Screenshot 2020-12-30 112140.png">`

What could be the reason or is there perhaps a better solution for my project?

Comment: use `@Path.Combine(Context.Request.PathBase, img.ImagePath)` instead of `@Context.Request.PathBase\@img.ImagePath`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It shows the right path in the Inspector: `background: url(\img\Adverts\1\Screenshot 2020-12-30 112140.png) no-repeat center;` but it occurs an error: `Failed to load resource: http://localhost:51629/suchanzeige/Advert/img%C2%ADverts%01Screenshot%202020-12-30%20112140.png -  the server responded with a status of 400 (Bad Request)` you see there are stange chars - can you help me?

Comment: the spaces are encoded in the url, that's normal. You should check for a working url first, not sure why such a static resource could be responded with `400`. That means there is some special handler on your server. I really expect another one named `404` (not found).